# Get values from one table and put into other table by select query but the items iterate over two times

Tags: python, mysql

```
 cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
                symbol = str(s)
                model_query = cursor.execute("SELECT id,model_name FROM models WHERE model_name= '%s'" % symbol)
                print(model_query)
                for k in model_query:
                    model_name = k[1]
                    model_id = k[0]
                    for j in doc.ents:
                        if model_name == s:
                            query = "INSERT INTO mt_entity_annotation(fk_pagecontent_id,annotation_text,fk_pattern_id,pattern) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                            parameters = (str(Page_no), str(j), str(model_id),str(model_name))
                            my_cursor.execute(query, parameters)
                            mydb.commit()
                        print("Success")
```

model_id and model_name are from the separate table and try to insert into mt_entity_annotation table by selecting but while entering into the table the details are iterating two times

Problem:

Inserting Table:

```
fk_pattern_id     annotation_text  pattern
3                    Jain_C         Hiatt
3                    Briston        Hiatt
3                    874569         Hiatt
(Problem)
3                    Jain_C         NULL
3                    Briston        NULL   ------->AVOID
3                    874569         NULL
```

j in doc.ents: doc.ents has various ENTITIES where I give annotation to text.

For eg:
Jain_C, Briston,874569

Comment: Please explain what `for j in doc.ents` is doing. (Use [edit] to add this info to your question)

Comment: I don't understand the point of the SELECT. If it was me, I'd ignore the application code for now, and instead focus on the sql.